# jmxPermissions.vbs sets no permissions

Tags: vsphere, eclipse-virgo

Im trying to start virgo server with vsphere sdk version 6.7 in my local machine and getting this error.

λ startup.bat

WARNING: jmxPermissions.vbs did not update the permissions of \vSphere Client SDK\html-client-sdk-6.7.0-8170180\vsphere-ui\server\configuration\org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.jmxremote.access.properties. Check the file has the correct permissions.

'Client' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

Error: Could not find or load main class Client

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have deployed the SDK on a Windows path with spaces - startup.bat thinks " Client SDK\html-client-sdk-6.7.0-8170180\vsphere-ui\server\" is a command line argument.

The simple fix is to move the SDK to a location without any spaces.

Kudos goes to my colleague Alex Marinov (https://www.linkedin.com/in/aleksandar-marinov/) for spotting this.